# Unity FindObjectOfType Problem on Object

Tags: unity

I have 3 "*GameObjects*". One of them is "*GameManager*".
the rest is players
each player has 2 script attached to them.
I want to find Run Script with FindObjectOfType method but only  player2.
But It returns me wrong  object Run script (player1). I want to second object Run script(player2' run script)  not first(player1 run script)  how to differentiate that while using FindObjectOfType.
Please Close this question if you find it duplicate. Because I couldn't find this question.

Please give an attention to the performance to not make it complicated.

Comment: Where is the script located that you want to find and who has to find it?

Comment: Why not use GetComponent<T> instead? If you only have 3 GameObjects in your entire application, then performance will not be an issue, might as well use FindObject("Player2"), or whatever player2 is named.